# regex nickname in discord.js

Tags: discord.js

I want to be deleted in nickname except for the letters a and z
i used this but its not working
i mean if ⍭ Brândy Shuirø. join the server bot set nickname to Brndy Shuir 
how can i do this

```
client.on('guildMemberAdd', (member) => {


    let nickkontrol = member.user.username.split("")

    if (!allLetters('a', 'z').some(letter => nickkontrol.includes(letter))) {
        member.Setnickname.replace(/([^a-z0-9]+)/gi, ' ');
    } else {
        return;
    }

    function allLetters(charA, charZ) {
        let a = [], i = charA.charCodeAt(0), j = charZ.charCodeAt(0);
        for (; i <= j; ++i) {
            a.push(String.fromCharCode(i))
        }
        return a;
    }

});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you're regex currently isn't saving spaces - You can fix this by just adding a space so it looks like `/([^a-z0-9 ]+)/gi`. You're replace function will also replace it with spaces instead of nothing.

Second, change `member.Setnickname.replace` to `member.setNickname(replace())` so you're final line should look like

```
member.setNickname(member.user.username.replace(/([^a-z0-9 ]+)/gi, ''))
```

If you still need more help, or this solution doesn't work, check [the official documentation on setNickname()](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/GuildMember?scrollTo=setNickname).

Comment: replace is undefined

Comment: Sorry, you're right, it should be `member.user.username.replace'

Comment: Its not worked when i put inside if(!allLetters) function

Comment: But when i put outside allLetters function its worked how can i fixed this ? Whats happen if Someone dont have forbidden letters in nickname ? Or whats happen if Someone have full forbidden letters nickname?